# Why is MySQL choosing that index?

Tags: mysql, index, amazon-rds

I have a large indexed table with over 35 million rows. Here are the indexes, with a naming convention that shows their sequential column order:

```
IDX_E93438363DAE128B,
IDX_LIST_ID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_DELETED,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_FIRST_NAME,
IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_LAST_UPDATED_AT
```

My query of this table on my medium Amazon RDS instance is taking upwards of 15 minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM contact
WHERE list_id = '014c7cbe-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'
AND subscribed = 1
AND deleted = 0
```

Using an `EXPLAIN` of the query I can see that MySQL is choosing to use the `IDX_LIST_ID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_DELETED` key, when I'd expect most of the other keys (`IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_...`) to be more optimal.

Should I just trust the engine? Is 17 or so minutes a realistic time to wait for a query on a table this large?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there could be a datatype problem.

Comment: Also could you please update the question with the output of  `show indexes from contact`? Cardinality plays a big role too.

Comment: I discovered something peculiar with MySQL optimizer, see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/what-strategy-does-mysql-optimizer-use-when-choosing-between-two-indexes. What happens if you create your indexes in a different order?

Comment: How many rows have `list_id = '014c7cba-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'`?

Answer (score 0):

17 minutes is not a reasonable time to wait. Try to provide an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM contact USE INDEX (IDX_LIST_ID_SUBSCRIBED_DELETED_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
WHERE list_id = '014c7cba-c124-11e5-b4ea-0a4287b2e8c5'
AND subscribed = 1
AND deleted = 0
```