# Index Design going incorrect

Tags: mysql, index

We have a table called Feedback as follows :

```
id            - int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment
vendor_Id     - int(10) unsigned    YES MUL     
created_At    - datetime CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
updated_At    - datetime(3)         
code          - int(11) YES     
feedback      - varchar(300)    YES

CREATE TABLE `Feedback` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vendor_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_At` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `uniqueKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerContactNumber` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `feedback_unique` (`uniqueKey `),
  KEY `codeIndex` (`vendor_Id`,`updated_At`,`code`),
  KEY `feedbackIndex` (`vendor_Id`,`code`,`feedback`,`updated_At`),
  CONSTRAINT `feedback_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_Id`) REFERENCES `Vendor` (`vendor_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and we need to create index for our Feedback Table.

So we added 3 indexes based on fields as part of where clause :

```
 index1 (vendor_Id, updated_At);
 codeIndex (vendor_Id, updated_At, code)
 feedbackIndex(vendor_Id, code, feedback, updated_At)
```

Now when we run the following query :

```
explain  select  'id', 'customerName', 'customerContactNumber', 'feedback', 'updated_At'
    from  Feedback
    where  vendor_Id = 1
      and  updated_At <  '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387'
      and  updated_At >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
      and  code is not null
      and  code >=0
      and  code <= 6
    order by  updated_At DESC
    limit  10
```

the mysql output says :

```
possible_keys : index1,codeIndex,feedbackIndex
keys : feedbackIndex
```

Am curious to know why the explain statement shows 'feedbackIndex' as the key selected. We were expecting it to select 'codeIndex'

There are other 2 queries :

```
explain  select  code, count(*) as count
    from  Feedback
    where  vendor_Id = 1
      and  updated_At <  '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387'
      and  updated_At >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
      and  code is not null
    group by  code
```

===> shows 'codeIndex' as key in output of explain statement. which is as  expected

```
explain  select  code, count(*) as count
    from  Feedback
    where  vendor_Id = 1
      and  updated_At <  '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387'
      and  updated_At >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
      and  code is not null
      and  feedback is not null
    group by  code`
```

===> shows 'feedbackIndex' as key in output of explain statement. which is as  expected

I can not figure out why our first query is showing feedbackIndex as the keys.

Comment: You query has `SELECT 'customerName', 'customerContactNumber'`. What are these, columns? It's better to have the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

When creating an optimal index, start with `=` -- `vendor_id` in your case.

Then you get *one* crack at a "range" -- `updated_at` or (in the first case) `code`.

Also (or alternatively) "covering" the query can be beneficial.  This is where all the columns mentioned in the `SELECT` exist in the `INDEX`.  In the case of `SELECT *`, that is all columns in the table, and that is usually to many.  When doing `code, count(*)`, only 3 or 4 columns are mentioned, so "covering" may be practical and beneficial.

The `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`) is included implicitly in any secondary key.

It is handy to provide the entire `EXPLAIN` when asking questions like these.  It is instructive to discuss "key_len" and how that tells you how many columns it used.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` is even better, since it is explicit.

Why did it pick `(vendor_Id, code, feedback, updated_At, id)` for the first query?  It is missing `created_at`, so it is not "covering".  Probably it decided that `vendor_id` (`=`) plus `code` (range) was slightly better than `vendor_id, updated_At`.  I would expect the latter (aka "Index1") to be better because it might be able to consume the `ORDER BY`.

`index1 (vendor_Id, updated_At)` is redundant (and can be `DROPped`) because of `codeIndex (vendor_Id, updated_At, code)`.

The second query needs `(vendor_Id, updated_At, code)` -- `=`, "range", "covering".  The query can be performed in the index, without touching the data.

The third query adds `feedback`; so it needs the columns of `(vendor_Id, code, feedback, updated_At)`, but it is hard to know whether that order is best or `(vendor_Id, updated_At, code, feedback)`.

What version are you using?  5.6, 5.7, and 8.0 have each made significant changes to optimizations in this area.

BTW, `and  code is not null` is redundant in the first query.

The first query cannot stop after 10 rows; this is because there is more than one "range" in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment than an answer, but it felt a bit long for a comment so I'll add it as an answer.

From my limited experience with MySQL the optimizer takes some weird decisions from time to time. Here is one observation I did:

[What strategy does MySQL optimizer use when choosing between two indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/what-strategy-does-mysql-optimizer-use-when-choosing-between-two-indexes)

In short, it appeared as if the optimizer picked the first possible index even though there where better indexes declared later. You may try to create the indexes in a different order and see if that changes what index it chooses.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rick for the explanation. I do agree the index1 (vendor_Id, updated_At) is redundant. We are currently using AWS Aurora which uses MYSQL 5.6. This is not an answer but due to length of my comment, I had to post it as a Answer.

I made the following new indexes :

```
codeIndex - ['vendor_Id', 'updated_At', 'code']
feedbackIndex - ['vendor_Id', 'updated_At', 'code', 'feedback']
```

Now, I ran the following 2 queries :

Query 1:

```
 EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON select  'id', 'customerName', 'customerContactNumber', 'code', 'feedback', 'updated_At'
    from  Feedback
    where  vendor_Id = 1
      and  updated_At <  '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387'
      and  updated_At >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
      and  code is not null
      and  code >=0
      and  code <= 6
    order by  updated_At DESC
    limit  10 
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Feedback",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "codeIndex",
          "feedbackIndex"
        ],
        "key": "codeIndex",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "vendor_Id"
        ],
        "key_length": "5",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 100,
        "using_index": true,
        "attached_condition": "((`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`updated_At` < '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387') and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`updated_At` >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000') and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`code` >= 0) and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`code` <= 6))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DB selects codeIndex which seems like a good idea. Since, I added fields to Select should I include those fields in the index as covering ? I thought it will just make the index table too huge for amount of fields I am using.

Query 2 :

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON  select  code, count(*) as count
    from  Feedback
    where  vendor_Id = 1
      and  updated_At <  '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387'
      and  updated_At >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
      and  code is not null
      and  feedback is not null
    group by  code;



{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Feedback",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "codeIndex",
          "feedbackIndex"
        ],
        "key": "codeIndex",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "vendor_Id"
        ],
        "key_length": "5",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 100,
        "index_condition": "((`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`updated_At` < '2017-11-15 12:58:12.387') and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`updated_At` >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000') and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`code` is not null))",
        "attached_condition": "((`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`vendor_Id` <=> 1) and (`dEbill`.`Feedback`.`feedback` is not null))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case the DB selects codeIndex --> I thought feedbackIndex was a better choice. Your thoughts ?  The output remains the same even when I define feedbackIndex as ['vendor_Id', 'code', 'feedback', 'updated_At']. Also,at this moment all are tables are empty.

Comment: EXPLAIN when the tables are empty is rather useless.

Comment: Strange.  First query:  It says `"using_index": true,`, yet there are many columns missing from the index.