# How does mysql optimiser chooses a composite Index

Tags: mysql, index, query-performance

I have a table with the following structure.

```
 -id (bigint|pk)
 -funnel_id (bigint|fk with funnels table)
 -affiliate_id (bigint|fk with affiliates table)
 -created_timestamp (bigint)
```

Observations

1. funnel_id has 10,000 unique records
2. affiliate_id has 15,000 unique records

I have various combinations of SELECT query on the table like:

```
1) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300;
2) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE funnel_id = 300;
3) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300 AND funnel_id = 300;
4) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300 AND funnel_id = 300 AND created_timestamp BETWEEN 600 AND 700;
```

So as per the rule, I should create a composite index with the below statement. Also, it gives me a **(100 score)** when I checked with the **EXPLAIN** keyword on the query.

```
CREATE INDEX ON tlb index_name(affiliate_id, funnel_id, created_timestamp)
```

But as soon as I create a foreign_key on funnel_id and on affiliate_id the optimizer starts picking up the foreign_key index and the **(100 score)** also reduces **(to 10)**.

But then I created a composite index on `(affiliate_id, funnel_id)`. Guess what happend next. The query optimizer again stated to pick the `(affiliate_id, funnel_id, created_timestamp)` index.

So my question here is, why the optimizer didn't pick the `(affiliate_id, funnel_id)` index. Guys, please let me know your views on this as it is getting a bit confusing.

Comment: This question is a couple of years old, but it appears as if the MySQL optimizer works in mysterious ways: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/what-strategy-does-mysql-optimizer-use-when-choosing-between-two-indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300;
2) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE funnel_id = 300;
3) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300 AND funnel_id = 300;
4) SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE affiliate_id = 300 AND funnel_id = 300 AND created_timestamp BETWEEN 600 AND 700;
```

`INDEX(affiliate_id, funnel_id, created timestamp)` handles queries 1,3,4, but not 2.  It is slightly suboptimal for 3 and 1 because it is bulkier than `INDEX(affiliate_id, funnel_id)` or `INDEX(affiliate_id)`

Depending on how/when you added the FKs, MySQL is sometimes smart enough to *not* add a new index because it can see that an adequate one exists.  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see the collection of indexes that exist now.  If you see some redundant indexes, `DROP` them.

If you are creating the table fresh, then this order *might* be best:

1. Create this table with `INDEX(affiliate_id, funnel_id, created timestamp)` and `INDEX(funnel_id)`.  Create other tables and their optimal indexes.
2. Then add the FKs.
3. Get rid of any shorter indexes which are a prefix of a longer one.  The FKs *should* remain happy that there is *some* index *starting* with the column it needs to check.

If you provide `CREATE TABLEs` for the various tables, plus a few `INSERTs`.  I may play around with it.

Back to your question of what the *Optmizer* does...

When only x is needed, and given a choice between `INDEX(x)` and `INDEX(x,y)`, the optimizer will pick the "smaller" index, namely `(x)`.  This is not always optimal.

An example is `INDEX(lat)`, `INDEX(lat, long)` and `WHERE lat BETWEEN ... AND long between ...`.  In this case the query *execution* would take advantage of the 2-column index for ICP (Index Condition Pushdown), but it seems to be too dumb to realize it.  It picks the 1-column index and has to work harder to check `long`.  (This issue *may* vary with versions of MySQL and MariaDB; there have been a lot of changes in the area.)