# does the order of index columns matter when we have equality operators?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-8.0

Given that I have the tables

```
CREATE TABLE `replies` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `repliable_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `repliable_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `threads` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `replies_count` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pinned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `threads_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `threads_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `threads_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
  KEY `threads_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `threads_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `threads_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `threads_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=927 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The `repliable_type` has 3 distinct values

```
select count(distinct (repliable_type)) from replies;
```

The `repliable_id` has 2002 distinct values

```
select count(distinct (repliable_id)) from replies;
```

I tried to execute the following query with different index combinations

```
select *, (select replies.id from replies
             where replies.repliable_type='App\\Models\\Thread'
               and repliable_id=threads.id
             order by replies.created_at DESC
             LIMIT 1) as reply_created_at
    from threads;
```

1. when I create a multicolumn index on replies with the columns `(repliable_type, repliable_id)`

```
alter table replies add index repliable_type_repliable_id
                (repliable_type,repliable_id);
```

The query above, does not even use the `reoliable_type_repliable_id` index and it takes forever to execute.

[image]

2. But when I create the index repliable_id_repliable_type ( change the order of the columns )

```
alter table replies
    add index repliable_id_repliable_type(repliable_id, repliable_type);
```

Then the query above uses the index and the query runs quite fast

[image]

I am really curious to understand why this happens.

I though that the order of the columns in an index doesn't matter when we have equality operators.

Is it because the `repliable_id` has more distinct values than the `repliable_type` and it narrows down the selection in the index ?

Or because the `repliable_id` is compared again the `threads.id` column, while the `repliable_type` is compared against a constant ?

Comment: Can you also try with an index on `(repliable_type, repliable_id, created_at)` ?

Comment: I am not near a pc to type a proper answer but your assumption *"I though that the order of the columns in an index doesn't matter when we have equality operators"* is correct. However in your specific query the two equality conditions are not similar. The first, `replies.repliable_type='App\\Models\\Thread'`, is against a constant while the second, `repliable_id=threads.id`, is against a column on another table. Thus, you have a correlated subquery(something like a LEFT JOIN) and both indexes can be used but with different plans.

Comment: Additionally, you have the `ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1` on a 3rd column which complicates matters even more.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I have tried that, it doesn't change anything. As long as the index starts with the column 'repliable_type', the result is the same. The database is not using the multicolumn index, instead it uses the index single column index 'created_at'.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  I guess it matters the fact that one column is compared against a constant and the other against another column. However, it is still not clear to me. is it because of the comparison or because of the fact that the `repliable_type` has only 3 distinct values while the `repliable_id` has 2002 distinct values. The point is that one column narrows down the selection more than the other.

Comment: No, I don't think that the 3 vs 2000 distinct values matters. Try adding the 3-column index I suggested and removing all others, to see if it is being used.

Comment: Funnily enough, I would propose that the index that isn’t used would be faster because it leads on the constant column. This means that you’re probably more likely to hit cached index pages/blocks/whatever MySQL calls them as your index seeks will be targeted around that constant value. The optimizer is most likely deciding otherwise because the join condition complicates it’s math. Of course, including the order by column to allow it to only read the one row each time would be faster again.

Comment: @AndrewSayer it could be that (in the first case) it is choosing a different index (`replies_created_at`) due to its size (keylen=5) compared to the huge size of the (wanted) index (keylen=1030).

Comment: Which also got me wondered: why on earth are we using a `varchar(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci` type for `repliable_type` column if there are only 3 possible values for it... That is (up to) 1020 bytes!

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but I did some observations a couple of years ago: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/what-strategy-does-mysql-optimizer-use-when-choosing-between-two-indexes

Answer (score 1):

This "composite" index should help:

```
replies:  INDEX(repliable_type, repliable_id, created_at)
```

(And `DROP INDEX repliable_type_repliable_id` since it is now in the way.  *This may be why you are not seeing an improvement.*)

Since that one seems to be giving you trouble, DROP any indexes starting with reliable_id, then

```
ADD INDEX(reliable_id, reliable_type, created_at)
```

If that fails, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as it stands when trying it, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: i've tried that combination. But again the database doesn't use that key. As long as the index starts with the column `repliable_type` it seems that the database ignores the index.

Comment: @OrestisuRic - Hmmm... I added to my Answer.